# Tool to build a relational db from .dat block files

Tags: blockchain, block, database

No need to elaborate too much. I'd like to build a real SQL db starting from the directory blocks. Is there any tool out there? I work on a mac and I'd prefer something cross OS if possible.

Answer (score -1):

parsing blockchain blk**.dat files - is very simple task. you can traverse all blocks from the begninning and put the data in your sql-database